# How do you create an array in a specific memory location? C

Tags: arrays, c, pointers, malloc

```
char string1[] = "dog";
char *string2 = string1 + strlen(string1) + 1;
printf("address of string1: %p\n", string1);
printf("address of string2: %p\n", string2);
string2 = malloc(sizeof(char)*4);
string2[0] ='c';string2[1] ='a';string2[2] ='t';string2[3] ='\0';
printf("address of string2: %p\n", string2);
```

> address of string1: 000000000061FE14
> address of string2: 000000000061FE18
> address of string2: 0000000000AD4D50

I want to make a 'cat' string at a memory location 0x61FE18, right after "dog\0"

Even though I've managed to successfully get the desired memory location of string2, the malloc function reassigns the location. I want the "cat" array to start at 0x61FE18  but malloc reassigns it to 0xAD4D50

Is there a way to allocate array to a desired starting location?

Comment: No, why would you need to? You can allocate a big blob of memory and assign pointers there however you want, though.

Comment: "I want to make a 'cat' string at a memory location 0x61FE18" --> `strcpy(0x61FE18, "cat");` and [reap the whirlwind](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/sow_the_wind,_reap_the_whirlwind#Proverb).

Comment: "Is there a way to allocate array to a desired starting location?" --> No standard way.

Answer (score 0):

you mean something like this?

```
unsigned char *data = malloc(1000);
if (data) {
    strcpy((char*)data, "cat"); // `data` points to "cat" followed by garbage
    strcpy((char*)data + 4, "dog"); // `data` points to "cat\0dog" garbage
    (int*)(data+24) = 0x01020304; // `data` points to "cat\0dog\0XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX\1\2\3\4"
                                  // depending on endianness and sizeof int
    free(data);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> How do you create an array in a specific memory location? C

> Is there a way to allocate array to a desired starting location?

No standard way.